# AngularJS - How do I get access to my template in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, directive

Given the following directive:

```
myApp.directive("test", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: "="
        },
        template: "<div id='dialog_{{model.dialogId}}'></div>",
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            alert($("dialog_" + scope.model.dialogId).length);  <-- This is 0
        }
    }
});
```

I need to run a jQuery UI method on the div in the template, but I can't seem to get a reference to it from the DOM in my link function.  Is there a way to run a function after the template has been added to the DOM?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/jP5Opu8uBqLCEla9vRhB See my comments as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have element property.
You can do something like   `var div= element.find("div");`
And if you want attach jquery plugin, just do `$(div).jqueryPlugin();`, you have to include jQuery, but if you don't angular provides jQuery Lite.

Comment: +1 Yup there is no reason to use `$(#dialog_" + ...)` provided jquery is included before angular, element will already be a jquery object... But you cannot do anything until angular has done its DOM manipulation (here attaching proper id parsing the interpolation).. `$timeout` will help that.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    $timeout(function () {
        alert($("#dialog_" + scope.model.dialogId).length);
    }, 0);
}
```

I forgot to put the # in front of the selector, but it still only works if I use the timeout.  Not sure why.

Comment: oh i think probably i was wrong in the plunker in my comment.. :P

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea to use the Id attribute in the template. What if there are multiple directives?

Comment: I'm generating a GUID as the dialogId, so it should always be unique.